# A sudden avalanche of upvotes

Tags: support, up-votes, serial-voting

I just received an avalanche of upvotes (12 upvotes to old answers within 1 or 2 minutes) See screenshot:

[image]

I'm not complaining, but it's a little surprising. Users with more privileges than me, do you know of what happened?

Comment: You can find some older topics about [meta-tag:serial-voting] here on meta. (Although people ask more often about serial downvotes.) There are several pointers to some basic information about this topic [in the corresponding tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/serial-voting/info).

Comment: (1) Don't worry about it. (2) If you do worry about it, *flag it*, don't post it on meta. (3) The automated script should be running in a couple of hours, don't worry about it.